# Get more than 25 Facebook wall posts

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to make an iPhone application - it's a Facebook wall viewer. However, I can't get more then 25 posts.

I heard that this is the default. Can this value be changed?

Here's my code:

```
- (void) getWallList {
    currentApiCall = GETWALLLIST;
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"/me/home" andDelegate:self]; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can change that one by setting the **limit** parameter to your Facebook api.
You can set that by passing **limit** to the params dict.

Have a look at [the Facebook api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) under the heading **Paging**, in which you can pass **limit** and **until** params

Take a look at the below sample for your reference.

```
params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", yourLimit,], @"limit", untilString, @"until", nil];
[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath:@"me/home" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

where `yourLimit` is the limit variable and you can set the `until`'s value from the api response with the key **paging**

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi @ryoichi, can u consider accepting the answer if it works?